# White Screen appears while animating fragments

Tags: android-fragments, animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to put slide-in-let and slide-out right animations while doing fragment transactions. The animation is working properly. But, I'm getting a white screen while animating the fragments. I tired with all possible solutions given in the google. But , none of them worked. This  is what I'm doing currently.

```
/** enter_from_left.xml **/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>

/** enter_from_right.xml **/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>


/** exit_to_left.xml **/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>

/** exit_to_right.xml **/

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:duration="500" />

</set>
```

Replacing Fragment in the container :

```
 public static void replaceAndAddToBackStack(final FragmentActivity activity, final int containerId,
                                                final Fragment fragment, String tag, int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit) {
        try {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit);
            transaction.replace(containerId, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

where `enter, exit, popEnter, popExit` refers to -> `R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right`

When I applied the same transition for Chrome custom Tabs, The transition was very smooth. There was no white screen. Why white screen is appearing only in fragment transactions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did u find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Try changing a transparent background to your framelayout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"/>
```

Kind regards!.